# Spark: how to save MulticlassMetrics confusion matrix

Tags: java, apache-spark

org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics is used when performing SVM classification, as follows.

```
 MulticlassMetrics metrics = new MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels.rdd());
 System.out.println(metics.confusionMatrix());
```

I want to persist some useful matrics in MulticlassMetics, e.g., precision, recall and confusion matrix. Anyone know how to do that? I can print them out but not sure how to save them to file in spark.

version: spark 1.3.0, java 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found MulticlassMetrics class from org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics can serve this purpose.

```
 MulticlassMetrics metrics = new MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels.rdd());
```

and write the resulting metrics (precision, recall, and confusion matrix) to a string RDD.

```
 JavaRDD<String> metricsResult = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(
       "Precision: " + metrics.precision(), 
       "\nRecall: " +metrics.recall(), 
       "\nConfusion metrics: \n" + metrics.confusionMatrix()));
```

after saveAsTextFile, the results could be in different part* files, you can use cat or getmerge command to read the complete pieces at once.

p.s., somehow I found precision and recall do not work as expected, but confusion matrix is correct.